# If Condition Comparison of two string format HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript

Hi I am new to javascript I wanted to implement a code where I have two var below
start time and end time is military format

```
  var start1= 08:00:00
  var endto=03:00:00
```

I wanted to create a condition where if my giventime is in between the `start1` and end to

Ex:

`giventime = 02:00:00` it will pass through because it is in the range of `08:00:00 - 03:00:00`

`giventime = 05:00:00` it will NOT pass through because it is NOT in the range of `08:00:00 - 03:00:00`

I tried to used the code below:

```
   var start1= 08:00:00
   var endto=03:00:00
   var giventime = 02:00:00 


if giventime>start1 && giventime<=endto {

//but doesnt work it should allow because 02:00:00 is withing the range of 
  start1 and endto
     }
```

Comment: You can parse the string and convert to seconds to be able to compare.

Comment: @Ele the strings can be compared as is

Comment: `var start1= 08:00:00` is a syntax error.

Comment: And having start be a higher value than end also doesn’t make much sense either .If the end value is supposed to be pm, then at least use 24 hour format. Then simple _string comparison_ is enough already to check what’s needed.

Comment: @04FS this is the case *"time is military format"*. `08:00:00` is 08 am. `08:00:00` to `03:00:00` is from day n at 08 am to day n+1 at 03 am

Answer (score 1):

You can add any date with given time and convert it to `Date` then use `getTime()` to get the `miliseconds`. Now check if `start > end` then minus 1 day from `start`

```js
var start1= '08:00:00'
   var endto='03:00:00'
   var givenTime = '02:00:00' 
function isTimeGreater(start,end,given){
   
   start = new Date(`Feb 12 2019 ${start}`).getTime();
   end = new Date(`Feb 12 2019 ${end}`).getTime();
   given = new Date(`Feb 12 2019 ${given}`).getTime();
   
   if(start > end){
   start -= 24*60*60 * 1000;
   
   }
   
   return start < given && given < end;
}
console.log(isTimeGreater(start1,endto,givenTime))
console.log(isTimeGreater(start1,endto,'04:00:00'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of the format you're going to have issues. Instead you could look at a time including date this can be done using the `new Date()` method.

For instance if you did `new Date("January 19, 2019 08:00:00")` for start and similarly did one for end date, you could compare the Date objects with your `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need a condition to check if the starting time is higher than the ending one.

In that case, you'll want to check if the given date is greater than the starting one **or** lesser than the ending time.

```
"02:00:00" > "08:00:00" || "02:00:00" < "03:00:00" // true
"05:00:00" > "08:00:00" || "05:00:00" < "03:00:00" // false

"02:00:00" > "03:00:00" && "02:00:00" < "08:00:00" // false
"05:00:00" > "03:00:00" && "05:00:00" < "08:00:00" // true
```

```js
function IsInTime(start, end, given)
{
    if (start < end)
    {
        return (given > start && given <= end);
    }
    return (given > start || given <= end);
}

var start1 = "08:00:00"
var endto = "03:00:00"
var giventime = "02:00:00"

if (IsInTime(start1, endto, giventime))
{
    console.log(giventime + " is in the range " + start1 + " - " + endto);
}
else
{
    console.log(giventime + " is NOT in the range " + start1 + " - " + endto);
}

start1 = "08:00:00"
endto = "03:00:00"
giventime = "05:00:00"

if (IsInTime(start1, endto, giventime))
{
    console.log(giventime + " is in the range " + start1 + " - " + endto);
}
else
{
    console.log(giventime + " is NOT in the range " + start1 + " - " + endto);
}

start1 = "03:00:00"
endto = "08:00:00"
giventime = "02:00:00"

if (IsInTime(start1, endto, giventime))
{
    console.log(giventime + " is in the range " + start1 + " - " + endto);
}
else
{
    console.log(giventime + " is NOT in the range " + start1 + " - " + endto);
}

start1 = "03:00:00"
endto = "08:00:00"
giventime = "05:00:00"

if (IsInTime(start1, endto, giventime))
{
    console.log(giventime + " is in the range " + start1 + " - " + endto);
}
else
{
    console.log(giventime + " is NOT in the range " + start1 + " - " + endto);
}
```